# Show incompatible (installed) apps in Play Store

Tags: google-play-store

It appears that the Play Store app (not website) is hiding apps which are incompatible with your device. Is there a way to disable this, so all apps, regardless of whether they are compatible or not are shown?
I am not asking for a way to install incompatible apps, just a way to find them in the Play Store.

One workaround is to search in the web version of the Play Store and then have the browser open it in the Play Store app where it then shows that the app is incompatible. But this is rather cumbersome.

The current behavior of hiding incompatible apps seems pretty counterproductive and might lead users to download knock-off apps instead because the user cannot find the official one if it is incompatible.

What is even weirder is that apparently when you have an app installed and a new version which is incompatible with your device gets published, you will not be notified and the app will not be listed under your "Installed" apps either. So you have to rely on the old version of the app itself to check for updates (I doubt many are doing that) to notify the user that they are using an outdated and potentially unsafe version.

Comment: Why would you as an end-user want to see an app in the app store that you can't install? Wouldn't that cause user confusion?

Comment: @MorrisonChang, I would be less confused if I knew that an app existed, but my device is outdated, compared to not being able to find an app (you possibly even have installed, see question), and having to open the browser just to find out that the app indeed exists (and being to view ratings, changelog, ...).